# Is Spring AOP possible with Dynamic Pointcuts?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have a use-case to use Spring AOP to intercept a method name that I store in a database. However, all of the work I have done with AOP before leads me to believe that the pointcut for the method I am intercepting must be hard-coded. Is there any way that I can read a list of method names from a table and create an Around advice for each method so that when those named methods are called the code is executed and all steps that need to occur after the method completed successful happens.

This is what I picture the design would be:

1. Load methods to create aspects for.
2. Create aspects.
3. Named method execution.
4. Path is pulled for record to execute a predefined method.

--

```
AFTER_STEPS
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PK | Method      | Description                         | Path
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | createFoo() | Create a Bar when a Foo is created. | createBar()
2  | createBar() | Log time when created.              | logCurTime()
```

--

The reason I am trying to do this is that our code base is extensive and broken into numerous applications. I want to use methods stored inside a common application included in all of the applications to communicate between the applications and create links in the data.

Like in the example above in one application I would execute a RESTful Service that will call a method named createFoo() and once it's created succesfully I want Spring AOP to trigger and invoke a method inside the Common Application to call a local method there named createBar(). Inside the createBar() method I will create the link to invoke the RESTful service within the second application using RestTemplate.exchange().

Creating a framework like this would allow me to link the applications in a way that currently doesn't exist, but I am not sure how feasible it is with the limits of AOP unclear in the documentation that I've read.

Comment: Why not just have a service that reads the table and acts accordingly.  AOP is for cross cutting code like logging and exception handling.  Your use case is not an example of this.

Comment: How will I know when the method I have named is executed if it doesn't change the database.

Comment: Can you explain to me how defining a method from a predefined list that can be invoked with AOP when placed in the database after a specific method execution is more dangerous than placing the same method call directly inside the executing method?